# replace class method with simple function

Tags: python, python-3.x

as an example here, i want to make a function to temporarily direct the stdout to a log file.

the tricky thing is that the codes have to keep the file handler and std sav for restoration after the redirect, i wrote it in class type to keep these two variables.

here below the full code:

```
class STDOUT2file:
    def __init__(self,prefix='report@'):

        now=dt.date.today()
        repname=repnameprefix=prefix+now.strftime("%Y%m%d")+'.txt'
        count=0
        while os.path.isfile(repname):
            count+=1
            repname=repnameprefix+(".%02d" %(count))
        self.sav=sys.stdout
        f=open(repname,'w')
        sys.stdout=f
        self.fname=repname
        self.fhr=f


    def off(self,msg=False):

        sys.stdout=self.sav
        self.fhr.close()
        if msg: 
            print('output to:'+self.fname)
        return
```

here is the code to apply it:

```
outbuf=STDOUT2file()

#codes to print out to stdout

outbuf.off(msg=True)
```

i want to make it more clean, read about 'closure' but it returns a function at the first call, kind of assigment type as similar as class.

i want it to be like:

STDOUT2file('on')

STDout2file('off',msg=True)

note: redirecting to stdout is an example i encountered just now.. what i am wondering is, any way other than class type to make simple functionality like those on/off type, which involve store/retrieval of state variables that should be better made invisible to outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can save state information in a function.  Just name the variable functionname.something and it will be saved.  For example:

```
def stdout2file(status, prefix='pre', msg=False):
    import datetime as dt
    import os
    import sys
    if not hasattr(stdout2file, 'sav'):
        stdout2file.sav = None
    if status == 'on':
        if stdout2file.sav:
            print('You have already triggered this once  Ignoring this request.')
        else:
            now = dt.date.today()
            repname = repnameprefix = prefix + now.strftime("%Y%m%d") + '.txt'
            count = 0
            while os.path.isfile(repname):
                count += 1
                repname = repnameprefix + (".%02d" %(count))
            stdout2file.sav = sys.stdout
            f = open(repname,'w')
            sys.stdout = f
            stdout2file.fhr = f
    elif status == 'off':
        if not stdout2file.sav:
            print('Redirect is "off" already.  Ignoring this request')
        else:
            sys.stdout = stdout2file.sav
            stdout2file.fhr.close()
            if msg:
                print('output to:' + stdout2file.fhr.name)
            stdout2file.sav = None
    else:
        print('Unrecognized request')
```

It is also possible to keep status information in mutable keyword parameters like so:

```
def stdout_toggle(prefix='pre', msg=False, _s=[None, None]):
    import datetime as dt
    import os
    import sys
    if _s[0] is None:
        now = dt.date.today()
        repname = repnameprefix = prefix + now.strftime("%Y%m%d") + '.txt'
        count = 0
        while os.path.isfile(repname):
            count += 1
            repname = repnameprefix + (".%02d" %(count))
        f = open(repname,'w')
        _s[:] = [sys.stdout, f]
        sys.stdout = f
    else:
        sys.stdout = _s[0]
        _s[1].close()
        if msg:
            print('output to:' + _s[1].name)
        _s[:] = [None, None]
```

The user can call the above without any arguments and it will toggle between the redirect between on and off.  The function remembers the current status through the keyword parameter `_s` which is a mutable list.

Although some consider the fact that mutable keyword parameters are preserved between function calls to be a language flaw, it is consistent with python philosophy.  It works because the default values for keyword parameters are assigned when the function is first *defined*, that is when the `def` statement is executed, and not when the function is *called*.  Consequently, `_s=[None, None]` is assigned once at definition and is free to vary thereafter.

Comment: your code works! btw, how to avoid the redirection was triggered twice? checking stdout2file.sav is none didn't work, as it is 'reference before it is defined', tkyou!

Comment: @timeislove OK.  I added checking so that, if there are two "on" or two "off" requests in a row, only the first will be processed.  If also will refuse to turn "off" if not first turned "on".

Comment: though the conversion works, it looks like more lines of codes than i expected, more than that of using class type... hmm...

Comment: What are you talking about? It should be the same number of lines as with the class version, since the only change is `self.save` into `stdout2file.sav`.

Comment: @timeislove There were some superfluous lines and I removed them.  For example, there was no need to keep `stdout2file.fname` around since the same information is in `stdout2file.fhr.name`.  Note also that I included three `import` statements in the function.  The class needs the same imports but they are not shown in the class definition.

Comment: @timeislove Note also that the function protects against multiple `on` requests, including giving informative error messages.  But there is nothing in the class approach to protect against multiple instantiations of the class (`on` switches) which could cause quite some confusion if they are turned off in the wrong order.

Comment: @John1024, yes.. what i was wondering is, as in my version i put default values to the parameters, so calling the function to make it on/off would nearly be the same name hence possible typo causing to call it twice, while in class approach would need dot method to make an off call, probably less chance to call it twice?! anyway, i think  your codes look very nice and a good demo on how to save the state or environment info in function call, thankyou very much!!!

Comment: @timeislove  Nice idea!  I added that too.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a context manager instead.  This idiom is common enough that it was included in the [PEP that introduced context managers](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) (slightly modified here):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def redirect_stdout(new_stdout):
    import sys
    save_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = new_stdout
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout = save_stdout
```

Or, if you like, the class-based version with `__enter__` and `__exit__`:

```
class redirect_stdout:
    """Context manager for temporarily redirecting stdout to another file

    docstring truncated
    """

    def __init__(self, new_target):
        self.new_target = new_target

    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_target = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = self.new_target
        return self.new_target

    def __exit__(self, exctype, excinst, exctb):
        sys.stdout = self.old_target
```

Raymond Hettinger actually [committed this to contextlib](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/63a1ee94b3ed), it will be included in python 3.4 as [`contextlib.redirect_stdout()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout).

Basic usage:

```
with open('somelogfile','a') as f:
    with stdout_redirected(f):
        print(something)
```

Comment: tks. but the redirect to stdout is just an example.. what i am asking is, if i want to do some functionalities that involve storing of certain states variable that would be retrieved later, and i want to encapsulate (or make it invisible) these variable, could i do it other than class type, which for some simple functions, like those on/off type, is an overkill.